# Convert any image to google map like?

Tags: google-maps

I know that there is a tool that allow you to convert any image to be like Google maps.  For instance, you can zoom in, zoom out, move the picture right and left. I've forgotten this tool, does anyone know it ?

Comment: http://www.google.pl/search?q=js+drag+zoom+image

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.org/) and maps api to create a [custom map type](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#MapTypeInterface) and use it just like google maps, it's not an automated process but is the best one in terms of customizations!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use map interface to display images over map. E.g. in google you can use [Ground overlays](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#GroundOverlays) or [Custom overlays](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays) from [Google maps API v3](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) - there is a very good documentation with examples ([ground overlay](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple.html), [custom overlay](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple.html)). Ground overlays seem to be simpler, you just put an image over the map and specify corner coordinates. Custom overlays allow for more functionality, but are more complex to use.

Or you can use the approach sketched by neko - tile the layer and use [`google.maps.ImageMapType` interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=cs#ImageMapType). But for smaller images I think the ground/custom overlays are much simpler solution.

You can also use opensource map interfaces like http://openlayers.org/ to accomplish the same thing as google does in a similar way (if you want to get rid of Google logo :-)).

Answer (score 1):

I am just working on a web project that need to display my images have features google map like.

I found some tools are very cool.

[Overscroll](http://www.azoffdesign.com/overscroll) jQuery plugin

[DimViewer](http://www.dimviewer.com/)